# Is a comma or semicolon used after the phrase, "that's all"?

Tags: commas, semicolons

In the sentence, "*Today, I watched some TV and studied for my exam, that's all*," would either a comma or semicolon go after "*that's all*"?

Comment: Any of a semicolon, comma, or period (full stop) would be just fine **before** (never _after_) the phrase "that's all" in your example. (**After** "that's all", only a period will do.)

Comment: Are you really asking about what goes **after** *that's all* or what goes **before** it?

Comment: Sentences don't end in commas.

Answer (score 1):

"That's all" is actually a complete sentence, so you can treat it like any other sentence.  You would most likely follow it with a period, because in conversation if someone said "that's all" they'd come to a full stop to indicate it really is *all*.  Of course, there are exceptions, and times you might want to use a comma or something else.

> I went to the store and bought milk, eggs, bread, apples, and potatoes, that's all -- but as I was leaving Tom the manager gave me a large bag of carrots for free!

As P.E. Dant mentions in his comment, because it is a complete sentence, you may precede it with a period, semicolon or a comma, depending on your writing style and what you want to say.